# venneuler subset not correctly plotted

Tags: r

I try to plot a venn where one set is a subset of another set. But for some reason it's not always plotted completely in the set but just a little bit outside the set. What am I doing wrong?

[image: example]

```
file <- read.csv(file="C:\\test.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")  

Lists <- list(file$A,file$B,file$C)
items <- sort(unique(unlist(Lists)))
MAT <- matrix(rep(0,length(items)*length(Lists)), ncol=3)
colnames(MAT) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(MAT) <- items
lapply(seq_along(Lists), function(i){

  MAT[items %in% Lists[[i]],i] <<- table(Lists[[i]])

})


library(venneuler)

v <- venneuler(MAT>0)
```

The csv file example, where C is a subset of B

```
A   B   C
37  16  16
38  25  25
58  35  35
103 36  36
106 37  37
108 48  66
117 52  80
196 58  90
206 66  97
240 74  
251 80  
266 90  
269 97  
325 226 
346 266 
353 298 
428 429 
575 514 
524
```

Comment: Please post what `MAT` is.  Your code is too convoluted to follow by inspection -- probably there's an easier way to get to your final matrix.  Once we can see what is in `MAT` it'll be easier to see why the Venn diagram isn't what you expected.

Comment: However -- rereading `?venneuler`, my bet is that you haven't converted your data to logicals, which is what the function needs, not simply collections of numbers.

Comment: And in the meantime, try `package:VennDiagram` . That may be easier for you to work with.

Comment: Hi MAT is the matrix.
so that wil be something like
`
          A B C
    575   1 0 0
524   0 1 0
`